# How can I add a specific timeout for one specific redux-offline request?

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-offline

I would like to add a timeout value for one specific request using redux-offline.
I want to achieve that it fires a timeout after x seconds (also while being offline) and therefor the discard function is being called with http error 408.

Is this possible without messing with the effect config?
If not how would a custom fetch effect config look like?